# Sort a vector of pairs by first element then by second element of the pair in C

Tags: c, sorting, point

If I have a structure POINT in C with coordinates x and y, what is the accepted way to sort it by the first element of the pair and then by second if the firsts are equal? I found many answer on this in C++ but not in C..can you help?

Comment: Probably the what you found for [tag:c++] can be used with [tag:c]. BTW it is a too broad question for SO.

Comment: Just use `qsort` and an appropriate compare function - see [man qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort).

Comment: For C++ it used some things that are not in C and Im not as experienced programmer to "convert "it from C++ to C so can you please help me?

Comment: I dont know how to write compare function for a structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several answers already, but their implementation seems to be too complicated ;)

```
struct pair
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

static inline int safe_cmp(int x, int y)
{
    return (x > y) - (x < y);
}

int lex_cmp_pairs(const void *left, const void *right)
{
    const struct pair *l = left;
    const struct pair *r = right;
    const int cmp_x = safe_cmp(l->x, r->x);
    const int cmp_y = safe_cmp(l->y, r->y);
    return (cmp_x == 0) ? cmp_y : cmp_x;
}

/* example usage: */
struct pair ps[] = { {3, 3}, {2, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 1} };
qsort(ps, 6, sizeof(struct pair), lex_cmp_pairs);
```

Please note, that you probably want to use `qsort_r` (GNU extension) if you're intending to sort in threaded environment.

Comment: Using subtraction for comparisons is a very bad practice. Try this with your function: create two struct point, set both x to 0, set a.y = INT_MAX, b.y = -1. Now, b is bigger than a in your function. set a.y to INT_MAX - 1 and it's suddenly smaller. This compare function is non-transitive. Also, undefined behavior through integer underflow if things get too small.

Comment: You're right (+1 to you for spotting it) - fixed by introducing safe comparison (but still without introducing unnecessary branching).

Comment: @PatrykObara: `qsort_r` is used to pass a context to the comparison function without resorting to a global variable, which is better for a threaded application, although you could use a global variable with tread local storage. It is not necessary here as the comparison function only uses the entry data.

Comment: @chqrlie show 2 pairs for which my comparison fails, please. Also - you don't know what is context of original question, so usage of `qsort_r` might be relevant.

Comment: @PatrykObara: My comment was referring to the previous comparison method, you must have been editing the message while I was commenting...

Comment: @chqrlie you, that's probably the case :) I made a comment in response to Art after editing my first answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) and an appropriate compare function, e.g.

```
// point type

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

// point compare function

int compare_points(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const Point *pt1 = p1;
    const Point *pt2 = p2;

    // do primary compare on x
    if (pt1->x > pt2->x)
        return 1;
    if (pt1->x < pt2->x)
        return -1;

    // pt1->x == pt2->x - do secondary compare on y...
    if (pt1->y > pt2->y)
        return 1;
    if (pt1->y < pt2->y)
        return -1;

    // pt1 == pt2
    return 0;        
}

// sort an array of points...

qsort(points, num_points, sizeof(Point), compare_points);
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/SpWSNQ)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: There's no need to cast from `void *` to a more specific pointer type. Also, relying on signed integer underflow is generally not recommended.

Comment: @unwind: good point on casts - thanks - answer updated. I'll make the compare logic a bit more robust shortly too...

Comment: This comparison function has the advantage in being fast, but if you need to deal with coordinates outside the range `-INT_MAX/2' to `+INT_MAX/2', you'd need to use a slower comparison function.

Comment: I tried this implementation but it left the order of structs untouched

Comment: @AdamKotvas: it's probably a simple error, but if you can't find the problem then post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @Paul R also your more robust solution cannot be compilated..it shows:  a value of type "const void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const Point *"

Comment: @AdamKotvas: try clicking the `LIVE DEMO` button above to see a full working example.

Comment: @Paul R oh thank you...I have to find out why its not working for me but thank you very much   for your help

Comment: @Paul R Its a problem with Visual studio :( I dunno why it throws error any ideas? Otherwise your code is awesome

Comment: @AdamKotvas Are you building the code as C++? It sounds like you are.

Comment: @unwind Im building it as win32 console project

Comment: As @unwind says, make sure your source file has a .c suffix (not .cpp), since you want to compile as C, not C++.

Comment: @unwind Yea thats kinda problem...I never found an option to have it as pure C project

Comment: The project doesn't have a language as such - it can even be a mixture of different languages - the language is normally determined by the suffix of each source file, so a .c source file is C, a .cpp source file is C++, etc. If your source code is in e.g. foo.cpp then change the file name to foo.c.

Comment: THANKS guys now its working !!

Answer (score 1):

you could either write a unique comparator-function

```
int comparator(POINT* p1, POINT* p2) {
    if (p1->x < p2->x) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (p1->x > p2->x) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (p1->y < p2->y) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (p1->y > p2->y) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and use it with any normal sort-implementation,

or you could define ranges of your coordinates (e.g 0 < x < 100)
with this assumption you could combine both coordinates in one integer and use any int-based sort-implementation

```
int createCombinedCoordinate(POINT* p1) {
    return P1->x * 100 + p1->y;
}
```